# Circular references in IE6 creating memory leaks

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

[I've found that all of these scripts, while doing the same thing create memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859907/which-version-leaks-memory-in-ie#comment12569860_9859907), the question is, why?

It would seem it's because of the circular references.

```
<script>
function runme() {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  node.onclick = function() {
    node.style.background = "red";
  }
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
function runme() {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  node.onclick = function() {}
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
var node = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(node);
function runme() {
  node.onclick = function() {}
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.onclick = empty;
document.body.appendChild(node);
function empty() {
}
</script>
```

Comment: what have you discovered so far?

Comment: I've found that all of them do. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you detect the leaks, but for me only the first 2 examples create a leak.(detected using [sIEve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/))

The reason: inside runme() you create a closure for **node**.

When you got leaks in all 4 examples, you should show, how you remove **node**(that's the point when the leak occures )

However: the solution is to remove events before removing an element: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/memory/leak.html